# What’s the difference between blubbering and sobbing?

Tags: word-usage, differences, terminology

I see these words used interchangeably, but it seems there’s a difference. Is there a significant difference between these 2 words?

Comment: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blubber) says of **blubber**:  informal disapproving.

Comment: Sobbing is crying, and blubbering is mumbling. Could overlap, but not identical.

Comment: Yes, there's a difference. _Sob_ is to cry strongly, with repeated peaks, and possible unsuccessful attempts to stop. _Blubber_, on the other hand, means to make noise repeatedly, and exude liquids; it's a member of both the "fluid" and the "excess" subclasses of [the BL- assonance class](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/bl.pdf).